# Never used Cloudflare - where is Cloudflare error message coming from?

Tags: networking, router

I am trying to understand why we are getting a Cloudlare error when we've never used Cloudflare.

We have a Peplink 210 which has two WAN ports and serves as our firewall and router.  One WAN port goes to Cox, the other is a new AT&T line.  Both have static IP addresses.

Traffic on the Cox line works as expected.  If port 80 is forwarded to a server and we browse to that external IP address, we see the website and if port 80 for that IP is not forwarded, the browser times out.

If I forward port 80 on one of the AT&T addresses to a web server I can browse to the site using the IP address.  But if the port is not forwarded, instead of timing out we get this error:

[image]

DNS is not involved since I'm going directly to the IP.  Where is this message coming from?

Comment: Weird. A Google search reveals at&t accidentally blocked cloudfare recently to residential customers. The error indicates you have a cloudfare IP address... What the network portion of the IP address you were assigned from at&t? **(Leave out the host portion)**

Comment: "Cloudflare owns [`1.1.1.1`] and uses it for its DNS service, but it appears that some networking gear — including AT&T’s routers — use it as an *internal* interface." -- Cloudflare also uses `1.0.0.1`. Just a guess, but maybe non-forwarded requests are somehow being redirected to one of these IPs via the equipment itself (perhaps AT&T’s modem or whatever you are using to connect to WAN2?).

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - I'm not well versed in IP, but our subnet mask is 255.255.255.240 and first octet is 23 (0001 0111).  I think that makes the mask /28, 32-28 is 4 bits of host which is binary 0001 or decimal 1.  I explain my calculation because it might be wrong.